# How to make Mouse settings on OSX match Windows Mouse Settings?

Tags: macos

I feel like mouse acceleration/other things are causing my mouse to feel weird. Any suggestions for having these things match my windows setup?

Comment: Maybe try explaining what your "windows setup" is in detail. OS X users are often not too familiar with Windows mouse acceleration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to install a third-party tool which allows customisable mouse acceleration to provide more settings than are normally available on OS X, e.g. http://triq.net/articles/mouse-acceleration-preference-pane-mac-os-x